# What is the performance impact of a large number of custom fields?

Tags: database, netsuite

What sort of performance impact should I expect from having a large number of custom fields on item and transaction records? Would it be worthwhile from a performance standpoint to remove custom fields that were created years ago but never used?

For example, we have something like 100 "Swatch" custom item fields that one of the teams who we consulted with to implement Netsuite created and never used. These fields are all of the "Image" type.

Seems like a waste, and my (limited) understanding of database technology would lead me to think that these are all occupying columns in a table somewhere in the underlying implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the performance benefits would be, and even if you run a test it is against NetSuite's TOS to publish any performance data. However, from the standpoint of the sanity for your administrators as well as your users, I believe it's always worth the effort to regularly clean up the lists/records/fields/forms/etc that you do not actually use.

Comment: @erictgrubaugh I had no idea it was against the TOS, how interesting. Thanks for the advice.